# "bieten" with the meaning of "to ensure"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

In a newspaper article, I tumbled on the following sentence: "Die Krankenkasse fordert politische Massnahmen, um dem Anstieg der [Krankenversicherungs]Prämien Einhalt zu bieten".

In this form, "bieten" does not seem to correspond to the usual meaning of "to offer", but it looks to have a stronger sense. I would have translated it with "to ensure" or "to guarantee", but in the Duden I do not find anything like that.

So, is my interpretation correct that in this sentence "bieten" corresponds to "gewährleisten" (to guarantee, to ensure), or is the meaning something else, or less strong? And is this meaning missing in the Duden, or have I just missed it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example sentence is slightly wrong. The verb is supposed to be *etw. / jmdm. Einhalt gebieten*, meaning "to stop sth. from happening / to stop so. from doing something". The author simply forgot the prefix *ge-*.

Comment: Interesting! I simply read over it and my error bell didn't ring.-- One may add that "gebieten" means "to command, to order", so the phrase "Einhalt gebieten" makes implicit sense (with "Einhalt" meaning "stop" or "arrest" in the sense of "arrested development").

Comment: Interesting -- the Duden lists ["Einhalt bieten"](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/einhalt%20bieten) as a synonym for "Paroli bieten". One could interpret that as a little weaker than "gebieten": "Paroli bieten" means to muster resistance; "Einhalt *bieten*" could be more of a challenge than the absolute command of "gebieten". The parallel use suggests itself because the perfect participles are indistinguishable ("ihm wurde Einhalt geboten" can be either verb).